# What is the word for doing something absentmindedly?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose a person throws his pen up and catches it by his one hand when he is deep in thought to solve a math problem. They don't know why they do it, but they just do and they do it unintentionally and inattentively. This behavior is generally not easy for a person to give up, but if one lessens his absentmindedness, he can stop this habit.  What is the word for this behavior?

Comment: If you said *John has an **automatic behavioural routine*** when he's thinking, I'd probably understand that to mean what you're getting at. But I don't suppose for one minute that's a standard "technical" term, and I can't think of any quick and easy alternative likely to be used in common parlance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe *Instinctively* or *Instinctive* is the word you are looking for.

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/instinctively

http://thesaurus.com/browse/instinctive

> Of, relating to, or prompted by instinct.
>
> Arising from impulse; spontaneous and unthinking: an instinctive mistrust of bureaucrats.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it's just ***a reflex***.

> an action that is performed without conscious thought as a response to a stimulus.

Or one could think of it as ***a subconscious impulse*** that forces you to act even before you realize it. That really looks like one did it *unconsciously*, but I feel in reality it's a *subconscious act.*

Comment: I can't really see a justifiable stimulus here.

Answer (score 1):

I would call that behavior:

- an unconscious habit
- a mindless reflex
- a bad habit
- a compulsion
- a compulsive habit

Comment: I beg to differ on _compulsion_. **Compulsion** is an urge to do something but it does not come to mind for no reason. It comes to mind (so the person is not **inattentive**) and it can be left undone _consciously_, whereas in my question the person is unaware of what he is doing due to his absentmindedness.

Comment: @Mistu4u, it's your question so you know best the scenario you are asking about.  However, by definition, compulsive behavior can fit the characteristics of the scenario you described: from the FreeDictionary.com - com·pul·sion (km-plshn) n. ***An uncontrollable impulse to perform an act, often repetitively***, as an unconscious mechanism to avoid unacceptable ideas and desires which, by themselves, arouse anxiety.

Comment: _unconsciously_ was the word I was thinking about. I think your first option is the most appropriate one.

Comment: Compulsive behaviours are often exhibited with full attention too!

Comment: It could also be positive.

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you want is simply the word *habit*, which you mention. *Habit* is [defined as:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/habit)

> an acquired behavior pattern regularly followed until it has become **almost** involuntary: *the habit of looking both ways before crossing the street.* (bold mine)

Or as:

> *psychol*  a learned behavioural response that has become associated with a particular situation, esp one frequently repeated

The thing you describe is not necessarily bad or detrimental, but it has become almost involuntary in a certain situation because of repetition. However, the person **could** stop doing it if someone pointed it out to him.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, you could be doing it "idly"

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/idly

> without any real purpose or reason

As in

> She sat in the waiting room, flicking idly through a magazine.

Comment: Yes, I'd say this fits better than the accepted answer. Op was happy with an adverb, though the question appeared to request a noun.

Answer (score 0):

The word  *[quirk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quirk#Noun)* (“an [idiosyncrasy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/idiosyncrasy#Noun); a slight glitch, [mannerism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mannerism); something unusual about the manner or style of something or someone”) often is used of such mannerisms.  Terms *[oddity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oddity)* and *[tic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tic#Noun)* may sometimes apply.

Answer (score 0):

If it is particularly well developed and occurs enough, one could say that it is ***a tic***; which can be [defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tic) as being

> a frequent usually unconscious quirk of behavior or speech

For example, a person who, like, frequently inserted like in the middle of, like, all sorts of, like, sentences, might be described as having a *verbal tic*, you know.